# Proving a version of maximum modulus principle elementarly.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, maximum-principle

There is this version of maximum modulus principle:

> If $P$ is a non-constant polynomial, then $|P|$ doesn't have a local maximum.

I know that if $P$ is non-constant, then $|P(z)| \stackrel{|z|\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$. But this only tells me that $|P|$ does not have a global maximum. It could have some locals, though. I am not supposed to use the open mapping theorem (I could prove that it implies the principle, though), nor the Gutzmer-Parseval inequality, nor anything related to integration theory.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can use mean value property of holomorphic function. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72885/mean-value-property-for-holomorphic-functions

Comment: You can do it purely algebraically, if you're not going to use any of the powerful results of basic complex analysis. By a change of variables, assume your local maximum is at $z=0$, and show that you can choose $z$ with $|z|=\delta$ so that $(z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_1z)/a_0>0$.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks! :)

(I think you meant $|\cdot|$ instead of $(\cdot)$ there)